# Can't convert a array or object into a JSON string for Session Storage

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to store an object that I created into the location storage using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse but something is going wrong. All the comments are my past tries. Every time that I try to store the elements, the is an error in my if statement in the loader() function that states "Cannot read property '0' of null" leading my to assume the array is empty.

```
function initial() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("run") == null) {

        /*  
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var idObject = {};
        idObject[form.elements[0].id].("false");
        for(var i = 1; i < form.length ; i++){
            idObject[form.elements[i].id].push("false");
        }   
        sessionStorage.setItem("savedIds",JSON.stringify(idObject));
        */

        /*  
        var ids = [
            {area:"kitchen",done:"true"},
            {area:"livingroom",done:"false"},
            {area:"bathroom",done:"false"},
            {area:"dining",done:"false"},
            {area:"bredroom",done:"false"}
        ]; 
        */

        /*
        var ids = {
            "kitchen":true,
            "livingroom":false,
            "bathroom":false,
            "dining":false,
            "bedroom":false};
        */

        var ids = ["false", "false", "false", "false", "false"];

        sessionStorage.setItem("savedIds", JSON.stringify(ids));

        localStorage.setItem("run", true);
    }
}

function loader() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("savedIds"));

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (obj[i] == "false") {
            document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
    function start(){
        initial();
        loader();
    //  complete();
    }


<body onload="start()">
<header align=center>Home Screen</header>
<p align=center id="result"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("currentAddress");
</script>

<ul align=center>
    <form id="myForm">
            <input type="button" name="area" id="kitchen" value="Kitchen">  
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById("kitchen").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Project/kitchen.html";
                    };
                </script> 
            <input type="button" name="area" id="livingroom" value="Livingroom" >
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById("livingroom").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Project/livingroom.html";
                    };
                </script>
            <input type="button" name="area" id="bathroom" value="Bathroom" >
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById("bathroom").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Project/bathroom.html";
                    };
                </script>
            <input type="button" name="area" id="dining" value="Dining" >
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById("dining").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Project/dining.html";
                    };
                </script>
            <input type="button" name="area" id="bedroom1" value="Bedroom 1" >
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById("bedroom1").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Project/bedroom1.html";
                    };
                </script>       
            <input type="button" name="area" id="send" value="Complete?" style="display: none";>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById("bedroom1").onclick = function () {
                        location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Project/sendinfo.html";
                    };
                </script>       
    </form>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked. What browser are you trying to run the code?

Comment: Are you making sure to call `initial()` before `loader()`?

Comment: The code is in chrome and I am running `initial()` before `loader()`

Comment: Are you sure there are elements in your form when you call loader()? (Also, you're returning after the first iteration of your for loop, no matter the value, so you'll only be loading the first value and no others.) What line is the error from, according to the log?

Comment: The if statement in loader has the error, the exact line with the if statement. As for the form, I tested that separately and it seemed to be working so I don't think it is that. Regardless, I will throw that code up! Also it was my intention to have initial run only once.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have bad data in your session storage? Eg. `savedIds` was set to `null` at some point while debugging/coding? I threw your code into a fiddle and it works fine until I manually go in and set `savedIds` to `null`. You can see whats in your session/local storage by going to the Developer Tools and opening the Application (Chrome) or Storage (FireFox) tab. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bkagq3ep/

Comment: Ok, I will give this a shot. See, It seems to run into the same issue that only the first button turns red instead of all of them.

Comment: Any idea on why all the buttons aren't turning red?